# InDesign EPUB omitting page 1 in iBook thumbnails

Tags: epub, apple-books, indesign

I create an InDesign document which I am exporting as a Fixed layout EPUB. When viewing in iBooks, page 1 (first page of the book itself, I'm not talking about the separate cover file) does not show up in the iBooks Thumbnails. Page 2 and on only appears in the iBooks Thumbnails.
Any ideas?

Thanks!
Kim